# Why Elvis (?.) operator doesn't work with async-await?

Tags: c#, windows, async-await, uwp, c#-6.0

Let's have a code like this (fragment of *App.xaml.xs*):

```cs
public class MethodClass
{
    public async Task Job()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Doing some sob");
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}

public MethodClass MyClass = null;

protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyClass?.Job(); // here goes NullreferenceException
    MyClass?.Job(); // works fine - does nothing
```

Why Elvis operator doesn't work with *async-await*? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure that `MyClass?.Job(); // works fine `? It is just do nothing without throwing exception

Comment: because your method Job is throwing exception

Comment: Define Job as async and do await inside method

Comment: @Fabio Yes - works fine in this case means that it does just nothing, just skips the line as MyCass is *null*.

Comment: I would imagine it's because you're essentially writing `await null`

Comment: @viveknuna What exception? The job is not going to be invoked at all in this case. Have you gave it a try?

Comment: because await MyClass?.Job() will be expended as await is null. and it will throw exception.

Comment: @Rob Seems like you are right, just haven't thought this way - the code `await (MyClass?.Job() ?? Task.Delay(1));` works fine. I think you can write the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The way `await` is translated is that first, `GetAwaiter()` is called on the awaited object (in your case, a `Task`). It then does some other complicated things, but those are not relevant here:

```
await MyClass?.Job();
```

Compiles to:

```
var awaiter = MyClass?.Job().GetAwaiter();
// more code
```

Since `Task.GetAwaiter()` is an instance method and you're calling it with a `null` `Task`, you get a `NullReferenceException`.

---

As a curiosity, it is possible to `await` a `null` awaitable, as long as its `GetAwaiter()` is an extension method that accepts `null`:

```
public class NullAwaitable { }

public static class Extensions
{
    public static TaskAwaiter GetAwaiter(this NullAwaitable _)
        => Task.CompletedTask.GetAwaiter();
}

public class MethodClass
{
    public NullAwaitable Job() => new NullAwaitable();
}

MethodClass MyClass = null;

await MyClass?.Job(); // works fine
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, as I think now about my question - it seems to be a dumb one. I think I gotta dive more into awaiters and some docs.